How to Create a Generic Data Fetching Hook in TypeScript for APIs with Different Response Structures?
I'm working on a movie discovery project where I need to fetch data from two APIs (Tmdb movie site) with different response structures (movies and genres endpoints). To avoid duplicating the same logic on every hook that I use to fetch data from the API, I know I can utilize generics but unfortunately when I try I get the error undefined.
Current genres hook
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import apiClient from "../services/api-client";
import { CanceledError } from "axios";

interface Genre {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface FetchGenreResponse {
  genres: Genre[];
}

const useGenres = () => {
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState<Genre[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const controller = new AbortController();
    apiClient
      .get<FetchGenreResponse>("/genre/movie/list", {
        signal: controller.signal,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setGenres(res.data.genres);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err instanceof CanceledError) return;
        setLoading(false);
        setError(err);
      });

    return () => controller.abort();
  }, []);

  return { genres, error, isLoading };
};

export default useGenres;

Current movies hook
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import apiClient from "../services/api-client";
import { CanceledError } from "axios";

interface FetchMoviesResponse {
  total_results: number;
  results: Movie[];
}

export interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  backdrop_path: string;
  vote_average: number;
}

const useMovies = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<Movie[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const controller = new AbortController();
    apiClient
      .get<FetchMoviesResponse>("/discover/movie", {
        signal: controller.signal,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setMovies(res.data.results);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err instanceof CanceledError) return;
        setLoading(false);
        setError(err);
      });

    return () => controller.abort();
  }, []);


  return { movies, error, isLoading };
};

export default useMovies;

But as you can see I've duplicated the same logic which is not a good practice.
I tried to extract a generic data-fetching hook to reduce redundancy, but it only works for the movies endpoint and returns undefined for genres. I believe this is because the generic hook expects a results array, which is present in the movies response but not in the genres response. The genres response uses a genres array instead.
My attempted solution
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import apiClient from "../services/api-client";
import { CanceledError } from "axios";

interface FetchResponse<T> {
  results: T[];
}

const useData = <T>(endpoint: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const controller = new AbortController();

    apiClient
      .get<FetchResponse<T>>(endpoint, {
        signal: controller.signal,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data.results);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err instanceof CanceledError) return;
        setLoading(false);
        setError(err);
      });

    return () => controller.abort();
  }, []);

  return { data, error, isLoading };
};

export default useData;

Here is the apiClient
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3",
  params: {
    key: "ABC",
  },
  headers: {
    accept: "application/json",
    Authorization:
      "Bearer XYZ",
  },
});

this is where I use the useData hook in movies
import useData from "./UseData";

export interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  backdrop_path: string;
  vote_average: number;
}

const useMovies = () => useData<Movie>("/discover/movie");

export default useMovies;

and this is where i use the useData hook in genres
import useData from "./UseData";

export interface Genre {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const useGenres = () => useData<Genre>("/genre/movie/list");

export default useGenres;

How can I create a generic data hook that can fetch data from both the endpoints without being specific to the attributes?

Can you [edit] to show where and how you are using your custom useData hook? It would also be helpful to share what these API responses look like so we can see what the usages would/should return. See [mcve].

Oh, ok, I think I see the problem. Do you mind also adding your apiClient code that processes these requests and returns the response objects?

Thank you so much for corrections you made, I'm still new here. I've included the requested code.

It looks like the issue is that one of your API functions returns response object with the shape { results: Movie[]; total_results: number; } while the other returns a response object with the shape { genres: Genre[]; }.
Instead of trying to generically type a FetchResponse object "payload" you could pass in the entire expected response interface for the API you are hitting.
Example:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import apiClient from "../services/api-client";
import { CanceledError } from "axios";

const useData = <FetchResponse>(endpoint: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<FetchResponse | undefined>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const controller = new AbortController();

    apiClient
      .get<FetchResponse>(endpoint, {
        signal: controller.signal,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setLoading(false); // clear loading before any early returns

        if (err instanceof CanceledError) return;
        setError(err);
      });

    return () => controller.abort();
  }, []);

  return { data, error, isLoading };
};

Example Usages:
import useData from "./UseData";

export interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  backdrop_path: string;
  vote_average: number;
}

interface FetchMoviesResponse {
  total_results: number;
  results: Movie[];
}

const useMovies = () => useData<FetchMoviesResponse>("/discover/movie");

export default useMovies;

import useData from "./UseData";

export interface Genre {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface FetchGenreResponse {
  genres: Genre[];
}

const useGenres = () => useData<FetchGenreResponse>("/genre/movie/list");

export default useGenres;


thank you so much man, it worked and most importantly i've understood where i went wrong. I'm very greatful. I was stuck for two days with this problem.

@OsteenOmega No worries, it turned out I didn't really need to see your Axios code (other than to confirm you weren't doing anything crazy there) and it really was just how you were typing the expected response objects. Cheers and good luck!

The request config object of the Axios API accepts a response data transformation function at the property transformResponse. I'll inline the documentation here:

// `transformResponse` allows changes to the response data to be made before
// it is passed to then/catch
transformResponse: function (data) {
  // Do whatever you want to transform the data

  return data;
},


You can accept this function as the second parameter of your generic hook useData and then use it to select/pick/transform the response data for each of the more specific hooks: genres and movies. Here's an example of what that might look like based on the code you provided:
(Complete example at the TypeScript Playground)
type UseDataResult<T> =
  | { // still loading
      data: undefined;
      error: undefined;
      isLoading: true;
    }
  | { // exception occurred
      data: undefined;
      error: unknown;
      isLoading: false;
    }
  | { // success: data received
      data: T;
      error: undefined;
      isLoading: false;
    };

function useData<Initial, Final>(
  endpoint: string,
  transformResponse: (value: Initial) => Final,
): UseDataResult<Final> {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Final | undefined>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<unknown>();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    (async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const axiosResponse = await apiClient.get(endpoint, {
          signal: controller.signal,
          transformResponse,
        });
        setData(axiosResponse.data);
        setError(undefined);
      } catch (cause) {
        setData(undefined);
        setError(cause);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    })();
    return () => controller.abort();
  }, []);
  return { data, error, isLoading } as UseDataResult<Final>;
}

const useMovies = () =>
  useData("/discover/movie", (data: { results: Movie[] }) => data.results);

const useGenres = () =>
  useData("/genre/movie/list", (data: { genres: Genre[] }) => data.genres);

